# She could be very unpleasant at times. (could is past or future?)

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

> She could be very unpleasant at times.

I think the word 'could' here is ambiguous.

What's the meaning of tense of could?

Comment: Here, "Could -is being used to show possibility." She could be unpleasant at times.=The is a chance that Sometimes,she could be unpleasant.

Comment: 'past possibility' or 'future possibility'?

Comment: Future possibility.

Comment: @Sam Are you sure?  I believe that 'can' is for present/future possibility while 'could' is for past possibility.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck past possibility also possible.( This usage of "could" is not restricted to the past tense)

Comment: This sounds much more natural as talking about the past.  "Sometimes, she was unpleasant."  It's not *impossible* that this is talking about the future, but it would depend heavily on context.

Comment: Yes, the default sense is "She had the capacity to be, sometimes, very unpleasant".